# Keras give error: ValueError: ('Could not interpret activation function identifier:'

Tags: python, keras, activation

Keras gives the error : ValueError: ('Could not interpret activation function identifier:', [, ])

importing the activations:

```
from keras.activations import relu, elu, linear, sigmoid
```

Defining  grid of parameters:

```
params = {'lr': [0.001, 0.1],
    'first_neuron':[5,9],
     'hidden_layers':[1,5,10],
     'batch_size': [30,40,50],
     'epochs': [40],
     'dropout': [0,0.2],
     'kernel_initializer': ['normal'],
     'optimizer': [Adam],
     #'loss':[mean_absolute_error],
     'activation':[],
     'last_activation':['linear']

     }
```

Calling a model :

```
regression__model = regression_model(X_air_train, y_air_train, X_air_valid, y_air_valid, params)
```

Comment: Could you explain why you would like to leave the activation parameter empty?

Comment: @hyper were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your activation parameter is empty.

To solve this...

```
from keras.activations import *
```

Note: the (*) sign allows you to use any of the activation functions in Keras without the need to specify their names.

```
params = {'lr': [0.001, 0.1],
'first_neuron':[5,9],
 'hidden_layers':[1,5,10],
 'batch_size': [30,40,50],
 'epochs': [40],
 'dropout': [0,0.2],
 'kernel_initializer': ['normal'],
 'optimizer': ['Adam'],  ## << notice the added quotation marks
 #'loss':[mean_absolute_error],
 'activation':['relu', 'elu', 'sigmoid'],
 'last_activation':['linear']

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Activation parameter is empty.

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question, and maybe provide some information about setting the activation parameter if the problem is just that?